# Algebraization of arithmetic and stronger theories?

Tags: lo.logic

Intuitionistic and classical propositional logic, and even classical first-order logic with identity, have algebraic counterparts. *Algebraizable logics*, 1989, by Willem J. Blok and Don Pigozzi, is a classical reference.

Is more now known about whether stronger systems are algebraizable?

Comment: Sure, instead of saying $x^3+y^3=z^3\to xyz=0$, say $\max((xyz)^2(1-(x^3+y^3-z^3)^2))=0$.

Comment: At least that was discovered after 1989. :)

Comment: For this case, Euler had everything needed by 1770.

Comment: Indeed. Anyway, I would like to know some about what such algebras look like if they exist.